# issues with php command line

Tags: php, cron

I have created a cron job at my webserver. That cron runs a php file every few hours. It's cache creating technique. But there's a problem - my cron command looks like this: `php -q /folder/phpfile.php` . When i run "phpfile.php" directly from my browser, everything is ok, but when CRON runs that file, it ALWAYS outputs "headers already sent" error to "error_log"! Mentioned php file DO begins with `if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();` but "error_log" show that exactly "session_start()" line is throwing the warning!

What's wrong? Why is everything ok when i run that file with browser, but when cron does it, "headers already sent" is generated?

Comment: What happens if you execute the PHP command yourself from the command line, rather than from the browser?

Comment: There wouldn't be a session available if it's running via CRON - where would the session cookie go?

Comment: Well, i have two options - to rewrite several php files needed by script or to duplicate code from those php files and modify it not to use session :\

Comment: Why not just use wget or curl instead of php -q?

Comment: I was told by server admin that i should use "php -q" in order to run php file using cron...

Comment: How could i use wget instead of php -q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why it works in browser is probably because you have different php.ini settings for your web server and for cli-php.

[output_buffering](http://lt2.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) directive is apperantly ON in your web-server and turned off in cli-php and it is right thing. Because no one wants to wait for content till script ends a job. We want to see what is happening when script is running.

Wrong thing is that you send header with a cli script. Session is not really need in terminal, is it?

Comment: "SESSION" is needed by some php file needed by the script :)

Comment: you might need to operate on session, but you do not need to send session cookie to terminal window. With session_start you do just that.