# facebook.php headers sent error when run as cronjob

Tags: php, facebook, header, cron

I have a file which includes facebook.php and it runs without any error if i run the URL directly. But when i run it as cronjob i get the following error in email

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a
href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session
cookie - headers already sent in
<b>/home/username/public_html/pathtofile/facebook.php</b> on line
<b>37</b><br />
```

And there is nothing being echoed before the inclusion of facebook.php since this file is being included at the top.

```
require('facebook.php');
include_once("config.php");
include_once("functions.php");
 $app_id = 'my_app_id';
 $app_secret = 'my_app_secret';
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $app_id,
   'secret' => $app_secret,
 ));
```

What could be the possible error?

Comment: How do you run this from cronjob, direct run with `php my-script.php` or web request like `curl http://example.com/my-script.php`?

Comment: php -q /home/username/public_html/pathtofile/filename.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your session is already started

```
if(!session_id()){
session_start();
}
```

Comment: public function __construct($config) {
       if (!session_id()) {
         session_start();
       }
       parent::__construct($config);
  }

Its already there

Comment: hey @SaadBashir did you resolve this? I'm getting the exact same error as you and I was just about to post a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here.  I wasn't able to pull much use from it, but I did find this (in case you haven't already seen it): [issues with php command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831797/issues-with-php-command-line)

I commented out the session_start() line in my facebook.php include file as a workaround ... seems to be working as best I can tell.  Doesn't make much sense to me, but did either of you come up with a definitive reason and/or direction?  I'm a little surprised there isn't more discussion/google results about it....

Comment: None yet! will try commenting session_start() as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with php command line so its better to run at cron with wget instead of php-q

i used wget http://exampl.com/url_for_script.php at cron url

and its worked for me